# Read txt file in Resorces folder using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filereader, embedded-resource, streamreader

My goal is to store a txt file in the Resources folder of a VB.Net application
I added the Dir.txt file with Project > Project Properties > Resources > Add Resources > Add Existing File.
I can see the file and can read it using a very odd few lines of code that involve using a hard coded path. Not ideal.
I have included some code that I have tested with NO RESULTS
I can use the OpenFileDialog but I do not want to go Fishing for the file!
Just Click a Button and display the file in the RichTextBox
Because the Project has a SQLite I have considered adding the file to its own table during the DB creation function
My two Questions are
**If the file is in the Resources Folder when I package it with Inno Setup will the file be in the exe file?

Can we explain a better way to accomplish clicking a button and adding the file to the RichTextBox?**

And YES these are imported

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection

  Private Sub btnGetCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetCode.Click
    'Dim openFileDialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    'Dim dr As DialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    'If dr = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    '    Dim openPath As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
    '    rtbViewCode.Text = File.ReadAllText(openPath)
    'End If '' This works but I do not want to go Fishing for the File

    'Why Does this code BELOW FAIL
    'Dim openPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Resource.Dir.txt")
    'rtbViewCode.Text = File.ReadAllText(openPath)

    'Why Does this code BELOW FAIL
    'Dim assmbly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    'Dim reader As New StreamReader(assmbly.GetManifestResourceStream("frmViewFile.vb.Dir.txt"))
    'rtbViewCode.Text = reader.ReadToEnd


    'While this Code WORKS 
    Dim openP As String = "C:\Users\Dwight\source\repos\TestTwoGrids\TestTwoGrids\Resources\Dir.txt"
    rtbViewCode.Text = File.ReadAllText(openP)

    'End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already added the `Dir.txt` resource file (`Project > Project Properties > Resources > Add Resources > Add Existing File`) and assigned an Alias, let's say `DirTxt`

[image: Resources.resx example]

The only thing left to do is to insert its content to the RichBox as follows:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = My.Resources.DirTxt
End Sub
```

And yes, once you compile it, the resources are embodied inside the executable file.

If this helps you, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: It is telling me My.Resources.Dir.txt is not a member of the project name? any thoughts I do now see the same screen shot you have ?

Comment: How did you call the resource? I mean what is the alias for the Dir.txt file? When you add a resource like Dir.txt, you name the alias as whatever you want. Usually it takes out the extension (so it may be My.Resources.Dir for your case), in my case I renamed the alias to DirTxt

Comment: as you can see highligthed in the image, that is why in my case was My.Resorces.DirTxt

Comment: OK went back and added it Now I see the same screen shot. And this is how I need to make the call  rtbViewCode.Text = My.Resources.Dir IT Does not like the file extention .txt when making the call Talk About confusion Thanks for the HELP